# method onFocusChangeListener called only once

Tags: android

I am developing sample app to test the `OnFocusChangeListener`, I kept debug point on it's method `public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)`and I observed that the method is invoked only once i.e. after launching the app, up to this it's fine but when I scrolled down to the next list item, the item was focused but method isn't invoked. I know I am missing some little one. can you please help me to get rid off this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Note** The scrolling is done by using Remote control's D-Pad

java class:

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener{
    String[] items={"iOS","android","Symbian",};
    //GridView lst;
    ListView lst;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lst.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);


        }



    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FOCUSED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to solve the issue but still I don't know why the `OnFocuschangeListener` was not working? I solved it by implementing `OnItemSelectedListener`

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    String[] items={"iOS","android","Symbian",};
    //GridView lst;
    ListView lst;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lst.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);


        }



    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Focus is called when you use tracking ball or remote to make it highlight (Without touching. An example could be in an android TV where you are navigating with left,up,down,right button.)

You need an onItemSelected for selection. onItemClickListener for click.

Comment: @thanks for ur answer,  I did it with posted answer. ..thank u so much